# Calling method depending on environment in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two methods, implementations differ depending on environment (dev / prod).
Is it a good idea to use a variable from application.properties? For example:

```
production-mode:true
```

and use it:

```
@Value("${production-mode}")
private boolean isProd;
...
if (isProd) {
    methodForProduction();
} else {
    methodForDevelopment();
}
```

Do you have any suggestions or could you point me in the direction of some useful resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot comes with a profile management system that allow you to active or swap functionnality and behaviour depending on those.
Here is a link to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles).

What you could do is create an interface and 2 implementations as such :

```java
public interface MyClass {
    void myMethod();
}

public class MyClassForDevelopment implements MyClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() { // your code for developement }
}

public class MyClassForProduction implements MyClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() { // your code for production }
}
```

And use the configuration of Spring boot as such :

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public MyClass myClassDev() { return new MyClassForDevelopment(); }

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public MyClass myClassProd() { return new MyClassForProduction(); }

}
```